# A simple LaTex editor

Tags: editors

Can you suggest a LaTeX editor that can be used to typeset math documents? I've never used but I want to adopt one. Please, something simple to use

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides) you can find a list of editors. I prefer [Texmaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/).

Comment: I tried to download LyX but there's no version for Windows 8

Comment: It should work on win 8 see [Supported Windows versions: Windows Vista, 7, 8.1 and 10.](https://wiki.lyx.org/Windows/Windows), [Windows binaries (Windows 7 and later)](http://www.lyx.org/Download)

Comment: in the middle of the installation it stops because there are problems

Comment: finally I tried an online versions for sharing. It should be good to get start